# Falco k8s, when add an exception, some fields become null

Tags: kubernetes, falco

If I add an exception to the rule 'The docker client is executed in a container' like:

```
exceptions:
  - name: kube_mon
    fields: [container.image.repository, k8s.ns.name, k8s.pod.name]
    comps: [=, =, startswith]
    values:
      - [repo/myimg, myns, my-pod-]
```

I start receiving Warnings where the mentioned fields are null (instead of not receiving them at all) :
screen:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RTiJ.png

Same exceptions added to the rule 'Contact K8S API Server From Container' works ok and my pods are filtered out from logging.
How can I solve it?
Thanks. 
Falco 0.31.1
Chart falco-1.17.4

Comment: Are you still facing this issue? If so, you could ask in the falco channel in the Kubernetes slack or open an issue on GitHub

Comment: @trallnag I dont know because I moved to another project. Probably its solved in more recent version.
thanks for your suggestion.